# Naming conventions of MySQL versions

Tags: mysql

I'm just collecting version numbers of software running on our servers. Doing this I realize that all MySQL installations have "cll" appended to the version number. What does this mean?

Comment: Can anyone give me a clue please why my question is voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I followed the request of Dennis Kaarsemaker and asked the provider respectively the manufacturer (cPanel) and got the following definit answer:

> **"5.5.31-cll" does not indicate the use of Cloud Linux. This is the
>   standard naming convention for MySQL on cPanel.** You will see this
>   version on servers that do not use Cloud Linux. EX:
>
> ```
>    `Server version 5.5.31-cll`
> ```
>
> However, if you are using MySQL
>   Governor with Cloud Linux, it does bring in its own version of MySQL
>   to make it possible to monitor usage & throttle abusers. These MySQL
>   packages use the "cl-MySQL*" naming convention.

Answer (score -1):

'cll' is a suffix added by cloudlinux, so it means you are using their package.

Comment: All our servers run on rented Virtuozzo VPSs using CENTOS templates. Configuration is done with cPanel/WHM. All installations are more or less standard. I see no clues that CloudLinux components are used.

Comment: Ask your VPS provider what he's done then...